# Force scrollbar visibility on MacOS not working on all pages

Tags: css, macos, safari, webkit, scrollbar

I have a macOS application, which at some point loads a web page into a webview (WKWebView).From that page I need to go to two more pages.
So, I want that when I have scrollable content in the webview, to display scrollbar all the time, regardless of the setting in system preferences.

I tried this solution:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

It works for the first page which is loaded, but for the next page, scrollbar isn't visible...

Please, help me...